# StringTemplate V4 ''->" syntax

Tags: antlr, antlr4, stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4, language-translation

Newbie (or silly) question:

I'm trying to use StringTemplate V4 to convert a language to another one, like C to nuSMV. So far I noticed that I have to "instrumentate" my grammar file (g4) to inform what I'm supposed to replace. For instance:

```
atom
  :  ID ->  var(id={$ID.text})
  ;
```

When I try to run that code, I get the following exception in my Eclipse:

```
syntax error: '->' came as a complete surprise to me while looking for rule element (org.antlr:antlr4-maven-plugin:4.2.2:antlr4:antlr:generate-sources)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

v4 ANTLR does not support ST directly. Sorry. We intend for people to use ST within a listener or visitor.

Comment: Thanks! I think it's a better choice.

Comment: @SamuelCardoso Then you should consider to accept this answer to reward the effort of The ANTLR Guy